Capture all inbuilt trackpad events and cancel some touch events
I'm trying to capture all trackpad events at OS level and disable few of them - say the ones in left half of trackpad. Following this question, I could level listen to events in current window view with following code.

final class AppKitTouchesView: NSView {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        // We're interested in `.indirect` touches only.
        allowedTouchTypes = [.indirect]
        // We'd like to receive resting touches as well.
        wantsRestingTouches = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func handleTouches(with event: NSEvent) {
        // 1. Change `in` parameter to listen events at OS level
        // 2. Disable all events with `touch.normalizedPosition.x < 0.5`
        let touches = event.touches(matching: .touching, in: self)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(with event: NSEvent) {
        handleTouches(with: event)
    }
}


I'd to accomplish two things further.

Change in parameter to listen events at OS level
Disable all touch events on some condition - say touch.normalizedPosition.x < 0.5


See Accessing touch events in a global monitor throws an error
